# In mysql or postgres, is there a limit to the size of an IN (1,2,n) statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, postgresql, limit

I've got quite a few SQL statements like such:

`SELECT foo FROM things WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3..n)`

Is there a known limit to the number of elements that will safely fit in an IN clause like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no technical limit, but there is a some kind of 'good sense' limit..

Having too much elements in the IN clause means the query have probably a bad design (imho)

Comment: You can almost always replace IN with a some JOIN statement, unless you have the list from external (non-SQL) source.

Comment: and if the list is external, you can always insert it into a temporary table and then do a join, which maybe after creating some indices might turn out to be a good plan

Comment: @araqnid: can the views be used with external source?

Comment: not directly, without some magic, but you could create a temp table, do a COPY to populate it from your app, index/analyze the temp table and do a join. Long-winded, and only useful if it's a lot of values that have to be sent over.

Of course, if you do need some sort of external source and you can write a function to obtain those values, that will work too- either use the fn directly in the query or spool it to a temp table.

Comment: @Strae in PostgreSQL 9.1 there is a possibility to use external data as a table. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers.

Answer (score 8):

The 1000 limit in PostgreSQL is not a hard limit, it is a optimization limit, i.e; after 1000 PostgreSQL doesn't handle it very well. Of course I have to ask what in the world are you doing with a 1000 entry IN clause.

Answer (score 5):

For MySQL, from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

The number of values in the `IN` list is only limited by the [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value.

Answer (score 2):

I've used it, in dynamic queries created for postgres with sqlalchemy, with over 25k parameters. Also, they were passed to python functions via positional parameters (*args).... but I didn't notice a slowdown in my case. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

No, but be careful when using the IN statement. If you use a subquery in your IN statement, performance might be negatively impacted because SQL Server must generate the entire result set and essentially build a potentially large IF statement internally.

For example, something like `Select * From MyTable where MyColumn IN (Select myColumn from AnotherTable)` might be somewhat slow if the subquery returns a large number of rows. Often times it's more efficient to use EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Postgres has a limit of 1000....can't find any docco to support that though.

Comment: That might be Oracle.